# Access Subview in another ViewController?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, subview

how can i access a subview i added in another view controller? Like

**DummyViewController:**

```
- Subview 1
- Subview 2
```

**TestViewController:**

```
- Subview 3
```

Now I want to access the properties of Subview 1 (DummyViewController) in Subview 3 (TestViewController).

Thank + Regards

Answer (score 0):

Put or send the shared properties in another object above both dummyviewcontroller and testviewcontroller (the M of the MVC pattern) and pass a reference to that model object down to whoever needs those properties.

Or have whatever is above those two view controllers put a reference to the dummyviewcontroller into the testviewcontroller subview.

Answer (score 0):

## import "DummyViewController.h"

DummyViewController *dummy = [[DummyViewController alloc] init];

```
dummy.subview1.button.hidden = NO;
```

Here I am accessing the button of subview1 in testviewcontroller.

hope this works for u...

Comment: i tried that, but that doesn't gives me the current instance of that view!

Answer (score 0):

In "DummyViewController" in viewDidLoad

```
subView1.tag = 1;
subView2.tag = 2;
```

In TestViewController

```
DummyViewController *dummy = [[DummyViewController alloc] init];
UIView subview1 = [dummy.view viewWithTag:1];
```

Comment: does this get me the same instance?

Answer (score 0):

The added sub views can be found in the properties of UIView.

```
property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews
```

But you need something else to distinguish what you want. You can assign tag property to the view, or distinguish by the class of the view.

The convenience method -viewWithTag: of UIView can help you find out the view with unique tag.